# How to drag and drop any object with same code?

Tags: ios, iphone, drag-and-drop

I'm building an app for the iPhone and I need to drag and drop allot of different objects.

I have found allot of separate ways to drag and drop UIImageViews, UIButtons etc. But I was wondering if there is a universal way to program any object to able to drag and drop?

Comment: Drag and drop where?  In Xcode?  In iOS? (is that even possible?)

Comment: I want to drag and drop any object on the iPhone screen in iOS.

Comment: Drag it where?  The only application that gets drag events on the iOS screen is the Springboard.  I don't think there's any such thing as drag and drop to any other application.

Comment: I only want to move it around on the screen in the same view.

Comment: OK, sorry, thought you were trying to drag things around between views, which would be really hard to do in iOS.  :)

Comment: oh that's OK.. yeah I could imagine haha ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider using one or more UIGestureRecognizers for each view. Here's a reference to the docs.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html